# Sheets Get value from the earliest/latest date and time from column

Tags: google-sheets, max, min

I have a table that is filled with dates and values.
I have 2 columns. One with date in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. Another with percentage number.
I need to automatically calculate the difference between the last value (percentage number) in month (date and time, for example 2021-03-11 22:55:00) and first value (percentage number) in month (date and time, for example 2021-03-10 03:04:00).
Also I need to automatically calculate the difference between the first value (percentage number) in current month (date and time, for example 2021-03-11 22:55:00) and first value (percentage number) in previous month (date and time, for example 2021-03-10 03:04:00).

He is the table
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_zxoGv02ki1qYdngMP28QGc0VxA3BfNzn7vyX1yA0q8/edit?usp=sharing

With red I highlighted desired values. With yellow needed result.

[Last Date - First date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ5CB.png)

[First Date - First date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Zc6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of FILTER(), MAX(), MIN(), and EDATE() in this case.

For Last Date - First Date, you can try using this formula:

```
=FILTER(B:B, A:A=MAX(A:A)) - FILTER(B:B, A:A=MIN(A:A))
```

As for the First Date - First Date, you can try using this one. This works on the sample sheet that you've provided:

```
=MIN(FILTER(B:B, A:A > EDATE(MIN(A:A), +1))) - FILTER(B:B, A:A=MIN(A:A))
```

Comment: For Last Date - First Date, you can try using this formula:

`=FILTER(B:B, A:A=MAX(A:A)) - FILTER(B:B, A:A=MIN(A:A))`

It works only if I have no previous rows with previous dates.
I edited the file.
For First Date - First Date, you can try using this one. This works on the sample sheet that you've provided:
`=MIN(FILTER(B:B, A:A > EDATE(MIN(A:A), +1))) - FILTER(B:B, A:A=MIN(A:A))`

it works, but when I have many months it works in a wrong way. I updated the file to show how it should be at the end

Comment: How will you determine which month to calculate? Is this on a monthly basis(for example, in your updated sheet, there will be 3 calculation in the Last Date - First Date which is January, February, and March)? Same question with First Date - First Date.

Comment: If month is finished (January 2021, February 2021), than it will be first date- first date. When it is current month (March 2021), than it will be Last Date - First Date. Normally Last Date will be within a week from current date.

Comment: I'm not aware of a solution using google sheets formula with regards to your concern. I suggest using apps script for this one.

Comment: Anyway, thank you.
I was recommended to use VLOOKUP as an option. But need to understand how it works.

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest exploring Google Apps Script as well for a more flexible option. :)